# Keep displaying select tag value based on another select tag after submission. Also reset it to empty when reset button is used

Tags: php, html, html-select

I have made 2 `<select>` tags. Values shown in second one are dependent on the value chosen in the first one. Now I need help to do 2 things:

1. Reset both select tags to empty whenever reset button is clicked. Also empty them (revert back to state when page loads for the first time) when reset button is clicked after the [form](/questions/tagged/form) submission.
2. Keep displaying value in second select tag chosen by user after form submission.

HTML:

```
<form id="form" method="post">
    <select id="vehicle" name="vehicle" onchange="select(this.value)">
    <option disabled <?php if(isset($vehicle['type']) && $vehicle['type'] == "") echo 'selected'; ?>>Choose option</option>
    <option value="cars" <?php if(isset($vehicle['type']) && $vehicle['type'] == "cars") echo 'selected'; ?>>Cars</option>
    <option value="trains" <?php if(isset($vehicle['type']) && $vehicle['type'] == "trains") echo 'selected'; ?>>Trains</option>
    </select>
    <select id="brand" name="brand">
    <option data-option="cars">BMW</option>
    <option data-option="cars">Tesla</option>
    <option data-option="trains">Rajdhani Express</option>
    <option data-option="trains">The Flying Scotsman</option>
    </select>
    <input type="reset" name="reset" value="Reset">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
var vehicle = document.getElementById("vehicle");
var brand = document.getElementById("brand");
var brandOpt = brand.querySelectorAll("option");
function select(val)
{
    brand.innerHTML = '';
    for(var i = 0 ; i < brandOpt.length ; i++)
    {
        if(brandOpt[i].dataset.option === val)
        { brand.appendChild(brandOpt[i]); }
    }
    brand.selectedIndex = "0";
}
select(vehicle.value);
```

PHP:

```
$vehicle = array('type' => "", 'brand' => "");
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    if(isset($_POST['vehicle']) && isset($_POST['brand']))
    {
        $vehicle = array('type' => $_POST['vehicle'], 'brand' => $_POST['brand']);
    }
}
```

Above code is doing something that I want to do, but not everything. Like:

1. It's resetting the value of first select tag before submission but not after submission.
2. Value of second select tag is not resetting both before or after submission. I want it to reset every time the reset button is clicked.
3. Value of 2nd select tag jumps to first value option when submit button is clicked. I don't want that.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The Javascript to programmitcally select an option should look like this.

```js
brand.value = valueToSelect; // select a value
brand.value = ''; // remove selection
```

if you are using a full page refresh for the form submission, you'll need to store the value somehow (cookie, localstorage, url querystring, url hash) and collect it after the page has reloaded. For this $_COOKIE and a if condition to set the value in you phtml might be a cleaner solution than javascript in the full page refresh scenario.